# Modulus of $t^z$ where $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, geometry, analysis

Let $x\in \mathbb{C}$ be such that $\operatorname{Re} x>0$. Define the function $t \in(0, \infty) \mapsto t^{x-1} e^{-t}$. My proessor claims $|f(t)|=t^{\operatorname{Re} x-1} e^{-t}$. But I think it should be $|f(t)|=t^{\operatorname{Re} x-1}t^{i\operatorname{Im} x} e^{-t}$. Why is this not the case?

Comment: What does $y$ have to do with it?

Comment: @ACME ah sorry it has nothing to do with it

Comment: $|t^{iIm x}|=1$.

Comment: $|f(t)|$ has to be real. $t^{i y}$ is not real when $y\neq 0$ is real.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that $t^z:=e^{z\log t}$.  And so $\lvert t^x\rvert =\lvert e^{\Re x\log t}e^{i\Im x\log t}\rvert $.  And $\lvert e^{i\Im x\log t}\rvert =1$.

So it should be $\lvert t^{x-1}\rvert =t^{\Re(x-1)}$, and your professor is correct.